# Indexing order by columns

Tags: sql-server, index

Based on the query below it was suggested that I create an index on the column in the `order by` clause. My understanding is the sorting is done on the result set and not the table.

The person suggesting this insists it helps with performance. I don't think it does but I have been wrong once or twice before.

Thanks.

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Process_Activity_Id]
,[Process_Id]
,[Transaction_Type]
,[Company_Code]
,[Entity_Identifier]
,[Item_Request]
,[Item_Response]
,[Item_Description]
,[Status]
,[Status_Detail]
,[Start_Date]
,[End_Date]
,[Last_Update_Date]
FROM [dbo].[Process_Activity] (NOLOCK)
WHERE [Entity_Identifier] = @EntityIdentifier 
  AND [Status] = 'In_Progress' AND [Process_Id] = @ProcessId
ORDER BY [Message_Sequence] ASC
```

Comment: Can't you do a benchmark of both options? p.s. please use the code formatting tools - top of question window. p.p.s. welcome to the forum.

Comment: I'm sure you'd want to indicate what other indexes (if any) already exist on the table, and also why do you think you need that something "helps with performance". Looking at the query plan as it is now would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Based on:

```
WHERE [Entity_Identifier] = @EntityIdentifier 
AND [Status] = 'In_Progress' AND [Process_Id] = @ProcessId
ORDER BY [Message_Sequence] ASC
```

...the best thing is to have an index on

```
([Entity_Identifier], [Process_Id], [Message_Sequence]) WHERE [Status] = 'In_Progress'
```

As Status is filtered with a constant, a WHERE clause is going to be useful for this, so that the index only holds the "In_Progress" rows.

But you need to find the rows that match the Entity and Process, and to have those rows in Message_Sequence order (to save getting all the Message_Sequence values and then sorting them when the query runs).

The composite index like this will let the database engine seek into the appropriate Entity and Process, knowing that the first row it finds is the smallest Message_Sequence.

So the advice about indexing on Message_Sequence is kinda right, so long as you're only indexing on Message_Sequence within an index that's on Entity and Process, because those columns are more important.

If you only had an index on Message_Sequence, you'd be searching through the index for the first one that matched Entity and Process, which is only good for non-equality predicates (oh - I'm talking about this at the PASS Summit in Seattle this October).

Comment: Thanks for answering. This information helps quite a bit.

Answer (score -1):

In general, index are used during row selection. So, creating an index on combination of fields in the where clause, such as Entity_Identifier, Status, and Process_Id would help the performance. The exact field combination would depend on the nature of data you have in your table.

You are right, creating an index on the Message_Sequence would not help the performance because the sorting is done post selection.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think a composite index on Entity_Identifier, Status, Process_Id, and Message_Sequence would be most optimal.  That would allow a seek for the `WHERE` clause predicate plus provide the ordering needed for the `TOP` clause.